# Formal semantics of a simple object oriented language without inheritance but with self-referential objects

Tags: reference-request, semantics, object-oriented

Would you please point me to some papers or textbooks that describe rigorously a formal semantics/computational model of a simple object-oriented language? The language needs not accommodate inheritance, but objects must be potentially self-referential.

Comment: There's a semantics of Featherweight Java, which has, if I understand correctly, a form of inheritance (through casts) and self-reference would be what they call "recursion through this" or "recursion through self".
https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/papers/fj-toplas.pdf

Comment: Would KIm Bruce's [*Foundations of object-oriented languages: types and semantics*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/book/6267232) meet your requirements?

Comment: @Nift Yeah this is great. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinBerger Yes, thanks. Other folks who come by this thread: please feel free to continue to suggest titles. The more the better. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't insist on class-based object orientation, there is the *object-calculus* by Abadi/Cardelli, with numerous publications, see e.g. here: [http://lucacardelli.name/indexPast.html](http://lucacardelli.name/indexPast.html)